# Reducir el peso de un .exe con Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Estoy tratando de generar un .exe con Pyinstaller pero el ejecutable final me da un peso demasiado grande para lo que hace el programa. El **primer script** se trata de una calculadora que usa el teorema de Routh-Hurwitz para saber si un sistema es estable o inestable. Aquí utilizo la librería **Pandas** para generar una matriz (sólo estoy usando **DataFrame**). El **segundo script** es una ventana que diseñé en Qt Designer para hacer uso del primer script. Este diseño es muy simple, solo para ingresar unos coeficientes y un boton para calcular el resultado.

Logré generar un ejecutable con **sólo el segundo script** (sólo la ventana) y me da un peso aceptable. Pero cuando genero el ejecutable con los dos scripts me da un peso demasiado grande. Primero lo generé con `--onedir` y me da un peso de +800MB; después lo hice con `--onefile` y me da un peso de +300MB. La verdad no me parece bien que un programa tan simple tenga un peso tan grande.

Después de varios intentos más, llegué a la conclusión de que el culpable de ese peso tan grande es la librería `pandas`. Me di cuenta de eso porque generé un ejecutable con lo siguiente:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

print('Pandas ha sido importado')
```

y me daba un peso bastante grande, por más que **ni usé la librería**.

Además, me di cuenta de algo: cuando estaba en la consola (mientras se ejecutaba el pyinstaller), observé que se importaban **otras librerías** como por ejemplo: matplotlib, tkinter, PySide, etc; cuando yo no hago uso de esas librerías. Quizá eso también hace que el peso se incremente.

La verdad no se mucho sobre librerías, tal vez una haga uso de otra y por eso se importan, no lo sé. Lo único es que quiero saber como generar un ejecutable con un **peso menor**.

Y una última cosa, hago uso del DataFrame de pandas sólo para mostrar la matriz, nada más. Tal vez estoy importando una librería tan grande y no le estoy dando un uso adecuado. Si saben de otra librería que me pueda mostrar sólo la matriz y no pese mucho me dicen.

Comment: El ejecutable contiene todas las librerías que importas tanto si la usas como si no. Pandas es una librería muy grande, que a su vez depende de otras (numpy, matplotlib) que por tanto son incluidas también en el ejecutable. La solución sería tratar de implementarlo sin usar librerías de terceros como pandas o numpy

Comment: Gracias por la información @abulafia. Logré modificar mi código sin usar la librería pandas y el ejecutable pesó menos de 50MB.